# Django Search in many to many field

Tags: django, search

I am trying to create a search in my Django Rest Framework application I have a table of follower and following via one model called: UserFollowing and the code is:

```
class UserFollowing(TimeStampedModel):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name="following", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    following_user_id = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name="followers", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    @property
    def username(self):
        profile_instance = Profile.objects.get(user=self.user_id)
        username = profile_instance.profile_username
        return username

    @property
    def name(self):
        profile_instance = Profile.objects.get(user=self.user_id)
        name = profile_instance.name
        return name
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("user_id", "following_user_id")
        ordering = ["-user_id"]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Here everything works fine but in my following list API, I am appending username and name of the user. When I am getting a list of follower using:

```
paginator = PageNumberPagination()
query_set = UserFollowing.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
context = paginator.paginate_queryset(query_set, request)
serializer = UserFollowingSerializer(context, many=True)
```

Now I want to search via the result my serializer.data look like:

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 233,
            "username": "Username1",
            "user_profile_image": "url",
            "name": "CDE",
            "is_active": true,
            "created_at": "2020-07-25T06:00:31.786154Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-07-25T06:00:31.786185Z",
            "user_id": 88,
            "following_user_id": 53,
            "is_following": true
        },
        {
            "id": 49,
            "username": "username",
            "user_profile_image": "URL",
            "name": "ABC",
            "is_active": true,
            "created_at": "2020-07-15T08:32:35.352484Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-07-15T08:32:35.352517Z",
            "user_id": 88,
            "following_user_id": 144,
            "is_following": true
        }
    ]
}
```

So based on my output how can I search a result where username =  What can be the best way to search in this case.

Comment: Seems like you are using DRF, and if so, you can make use of DRF's [SearchFilter](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter)

Comment: I can use it but is it possible to search for the result. I am processing data via the model. Username doesn't exist in any current model. I have search through the result